# IDXs not assigned properly using felm() by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

It looks like there might be a bug in the `felm` function from the `lfe` package, but I'm posting this here to see if it might be an error in my thinking or a conflict in how information is available in `data.table`?

Simple example follows where we compare solutions from `lm()` with those of `felm()`.

```
# Testing LFE package output incorrect IDX values.
require(data.table)
require(lfe)

# Solutions of regression models by cylinder.
dt <- data.table(mtcars)
sol <- dt[, list(model=list(lm(mpg ~ 0 + wt + factor(gear)))), by=cyl]
sol2 <- dt[, list(model=list(felm(mpg ~ wt | gear, .SD))), by=cyl] # using felm()

# Get coefficients from both models.
coef <- sol[, list(coef=coef(model[[1]]),
                   idx=names(coef(model[[1]]))), keyby=cyl]
coef2 <- sol2[, getfe(model[[1]]), keyby=cyl]

# Visually compare values for different gears.
coef[idx%like%"gear"]
#    cyl     coef           idx
# 1:   4 36.14931 factor(gear)3
# 2:   4 41.05802 factor(gear)4
# 3:   4 39.05476 factor(gear)5
# 4:   6 32.89790 factor(gear)3
# 5:   6 31.93766 factor(gear)4
# 6:   6 30.61227 factor(gear)5
# 7:   8 25.03750 factor(gear)3
# 8:   8 23.60107 factor(gear)5

coef2
#    cyl   effect obs comp   fe idx
# 1:   4 36.14931   1    1 gear   3
# 2:   4 41.05802   8    1 gear   4
# 3:   4 39.05476   2    1 gear   5
# 4:   6 32.89790   2    1 gear   3
# 5:   6 31.93766   4    1 gear   4
# 6:   6 30.61227   1    1 gear   5
# 7:   8 25.03750  12    1 gear   3
# 8:   8 23.60107   2    1 gear   4 # should be 5!
```

The coefficients are all similar, but note the difference in IDX on line 8. The value of 23.60107 belongs to gear five, not four (there are no cars with eight cylinders and four gears in the dataset). Any ideas?

I need to use `felm()` because of the size of my original data. For now I've joined the correct IDs by column using `data.table(coef2, unique(dt, by=c("cyl", "gear")))`, but that's hardly optimal.

Comment: For completeness, you might want to show that it works correctly outside of data.table, `lapply(split(dt,dt$cyl), function(d) getfe(felm(mpg ~ wt | gear, data=d)))` vs `lapply(split(dt,dt$cyl), function(d) lm(mpg ~ 0 + wt + factor(gear), data=d)$coef)`. Probably better to file a bug report than a question here, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks @Frank, I did not know about `split`. Looks like a `data.table` issue. Filed bug report [#1493](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1493).